# How to get a '&str' from a NUL-terminated byte slice if the NUL terminator isn't at the end of the slice?

Tags: string, rust

While `CStr` is typically used for FFI, I am reading from a `&[u8]` which is NUL-terminated and is ensured to be valid UTF-8 so no checks are needed.

However the NUL terminator isn't necessarily at the end of the slice. What's a good way to get this as a `&str`?

It was suggested to use `CStr::from_bytes_with_nul`, but this panics on an interior `\0` character (when the `\0` isn't the last character).

Comment: note that your overall function should be also `unsafe`; it requires the caller to ensure that utf8_src is indeed in UTF-8 to avoid UB.

Comment: `let last_index = utf8_src.position(|&b| b == 0).map_or(utf8_src.len(), |i| i - 1)`?

Comment: In this case the first index of a nul byte is needed: eg: `memchr(utf8, 0, utf8.len())`

Comment: Ah I misread. If you know there is a null, then `let last_index = utf8_src.position(|&b| b == 0).unwrap()`?

Comment: eh, naming `last_index` may be confusing, though it makes sense in context of being last-index that is checked, and early-exit once nul is found.

Comment: @ker, dont think this is code-review, instead I'll remove my code and post as possible answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use iterator adaptors to find the index of the first zero byte:

```
pub unsafe fn str_from_u8_nul_utf8_unchecked(utf8_src: &[u8]) -> &str {
    let nul_range_end = utf8_src.iter()
        .position(|&c| c == b'\0')
        .unwrap_or(utf8_src.len()); // default to length if no `\0` present
    ::std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(&utf8_src[0..nul_range_end])
}
```

This has the major advantage of requiring one to catch all cases (like no 0 in the array).

If you want the version that checks for well-formed UTF-8:

```
pub fn str_from_u8_nul_utf8(utf8_src: &[u8]) -> Result<&str, std::str::Utf8Error> {
    let nul_range_end = utf8_src.iter()
        .position(|&c| c == b'\0')
        .unwrap_or(utf8_src.len()); // default to length if no `\0` present
    ::std::str::from_utf8(&utf8_src[0..nul_range_end])
}
```

Comment: This isn't an optimal solution since `position` will take quite a bit longer than, say, something like `memchr` would on a large string.

Comment: @BurntSushi5: Doesn't seem to be optimized indeed :(

Answer (score 2):

Three possible other ways of doing this, mostly using only functions from std.

```
use std::ffi::CStr;
use std::str;

fn str_from_null_terminated_utf8_safe(s: &[u8]) -> &str {
    if s.iter().any(|&x| x == 0) {
        unsafe { str_from_null_terminated_utf8(s) }
    } else {
        str::from_utf8(s).unwrap()
    }
}

// unsafe: s must contain a null byte
unsafe fn str_from_null_terminated_utf8(s: &[u8]) -> &str {
    CStr::from_ptr(s.as_ptr() as *const _).to_str().unwrap()
}

// unsafe: s must contain a null byte, and be valid utf-8
unsafe fn str_from_null_terminated_utf8_unchecked(s: &[u8]) -> &str {
    str::from_utf8_unchecked(CStr::from_ptr(s.as_ptr() as *const _).to_bytes())
}
```

---

As a slight aside: benchmark results for all the options in this thread:

With `s = b"\0"`

```
test dtwood::bench_str_from_null_terminated_utf8           ... bench:           9 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test dtwood::bench_str_from_null_terminated_utf8_safe      ... bench:          10 ns/iter (+/- 3)
test dtwood::bench_str_from_null_terminated_utf8_unchecked ... bench:           5 ns/iter (+/- 1)
test ideasman42::bench_str_from_u8_nul_utf8_unchecked      ... bench:           1 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test ker::bench_str_from_u8_nul_utf8                       ... bench:           4 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test ker::bench_str_from_u8_nul_utf8_unchecked             ... bench:           1 ns/iter (+/- 0)
```

with `s = b"abcdefghij\0klmnop"`

```
test dtwood::bench_str_from_null_terminated_utf8           ... bench:          15 ns/iter (+/- 2)
test dtwood::bench_str_from_null_terminated_utf8_safe      ... bench:          20 ns/iter (+/- 2)
test dtwood::bench_str_from_null_terminated_utf8_unchecked ... bench:           6 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test ideasman42::bench_str_from_u8_nul_utf8_unchecked      ... bench:           7 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test ker::bench_str_from_u8_nul_utf8                       ... bench:          15 ns/iter (+/- 2)
test ker::bench_str_from_u8_nul_utf8_unchecked             ... bench:           5 ns/iter (+/- 0)
```

with `s = b"abcdefghij" * 512 + "\0klmnopqrs"`

```
test dtwood::bench_str_from_null_terminated_utf8           ... bench:         351 ns/iter (+/- 35)
test dtwood::bench_str_from_null_terminated_utf8_safe      ... bench:       1,987 ns/iter (+/- 274)
test dtwood::bench_str_from_null_terminated_utf8_unchecked ... bench:         170 ns/iter (+/- 18)
test ideasman42::bench_str_from_u8_nul_utf8_unchecked      ... bench:       2,466 ns/iter (+/- 292)
test ker::bench_str_from_u8_nul_utf8                       ... bench:       1,971 ns/iter (+/- 209)
test ker::bench_str_from_u8_nul_utf8_unchecked             ... bench:       1,828 ns/iter (+/- 205)
```

So if you're super concerned about performance, probably best to benchmark with your particular data set - `dtwood::str:from_null_terminated_utf8_unchecked` seems to perform better with longer strings, but `ker::bench_str_from_u8_nul_utf8_unchecked` does better on small (< 20 character) strings.

Comment: I'd also encourage you to show the non-unchecked version, for the other people who find this answer but can't / don't want to guarantee the string is already UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

This example finds the first NUL byte using a simple `for` loop, then uses Rust's standard library to return the slice as a `&str` (referencing the original data - zero copy).

There may well be a better way to find the first NUL byte using closures:

```
pub unsafe fn str_from_u8_nul_utf8_unchecked(utf8_src: &[u8]) -> &str {
    // does Rust have a built-in 'memchr' equivalent? 
    let mut nul_range_end = 1_usize;
    for b in utf8_src {
        if *b == 0 {
            break;
        }
        nul_range_end += 1;
    }
    return ::std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(&utf8_src[0..nul_range_end]);
}
```

---

While `utf8_src.iter().position(|&c| c == b'\0').unwrap_or(utf8_src.len());` returns the first NUL byte (or the total length), Rust 1.15 does not optimize it into something like `memchr`, so a `for` loop might not be such a bad option for now.